# How to get the product of all values of a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table which has three columns (`Id`, `Item`, `Qty`) and it has 10 rows.
I want the product of all values present in `Qty` column.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ln()` and `exp()`:

```
select exp(sum(ln(qty))) as product
from t;
```

This seems highly unusual, though.  Normally you would want just the sum of the quantity:

```
select sum(qty)
from t;
```

And, in fact, you might just want that per item:

```
select item, sum(qty)
from t
group by item;
```